# Elasticsearch aggregation over several fields and push to an index

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

I'm having the following document in ElasticSearch, of the index **data-ip**

```
"ipAddress": "ip-A", "timestamp": "Day 1, Month A", "value": 1
"ipAddress": "ip-A", "timestamp": "Day 2, Month A", "value": 2
"ipAddress": "ip-B", "timestamp": "Day 3, Month B", "value": 3
"ipAddress": "ip-B", "timestamp": "Day 4, Month B", "value": 4
```

How can I write a query to, say, find the max/min/average value for specific fields, i.e. ipAddress, and then to create a new aggregated index, say **agg-data-ip** like this:

```
"ipAddress": "ip-A", "month": "Month A", "max_value": 2
"ipAddress": "ip-B", "month": "Month B", "max_value": 4
```

I check the documentation on ES about max aggregation but have no idea how to make a new index (or insert that new result to an existing **agg-data-ip**).

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: which version of ES you are using ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a terms aggregation with top hits aggregation, to achieve your required results

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "ip-add-terms": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "ipAddress.keyword"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "top_sales_hits": {
          "top_hits": {
            "sort": [
              {
                "value": {
                  "order": "desc"
                }
              }
            ],
            "_source": {
              "includes": [
                "ipAddress",
                "timestamp",
                "value"
              ]
            },
            "size": 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Result will be

```
"aggregations" : {
    "ip-add-terms" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "ip-A",
          "doc_count" : 2,
          "top_sales_hits" : {
            "hits" : {
              "total" : {
                "value" : 2,
                "relation" : "eq"
              },
              "max_score" : null,
              "hits" : [
                {
                  "_index" : "70792509",
                  "_type" : "_doc",
                  "_id" : "2",
                  "_score" : null,
                  "_source" : {
                    "ipAddress" : "ip-A",
                    "value" : 2,
                    "timestamp" : "Day 2, Month A"
                  },
                  "sort" : [
                    2
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "ip-B",
          "doc_count" : 2,
          "top_sales_hits" : {
            "hits" : {
              "total" : {
                "value" : 2,
                "relation" : "eq"
              },
              "max_score" : null,
              "hits" : [
                {
                  "_index" : "70792509",
                  "_type" : "_doc",
                  "_id" : "4",
                  "_score" : null,
                  "_source" : {
                    "ipAddress" : "ip-B",
                    "value" : 4,
                    "timestamp" : "Day 4, Month B"
                  },
                  "sort" : [
                    4
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

**If you want to create a new index with the aggregation result, then you can index the `_source` part of the aggregation result of top hits aggregation, into a new index.**

According to [this](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/is-there-a-standard-way-to-store-result-of-query-into-index/110650), you cannot push the aggregation result into a new index.

**Another way, is to use logstash and store the result into a new index.**

Comment: @hoangtuansu its been a long time ! Can you please accept and upvote the answer, if it helped you resolve your issue. TIA ;-)